# What are the DRY options for GitHub Action .yml workflows?

Tags: github-actions

I have many workflow.yaml files that their code and logic are quite similar.
This is a big DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) violation.

Ideally, I would create a `on: workflow_dispatch:'` workflow with a series of inputs. Then I call that workflow by other workflows.

If the above idea is not easily possible, what are the DRY options with GitHub workflows?

Comment: What's *not* supported are YAML anchors and aliases: https://github.community/t/support-for-yaml-anchors/16128 You could look into [composite run steps](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-run-steps-action) actions to reuse things, but they're limited in that you can't use actions within them, for example, only `run` steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own actions to split off common logic and use it from your workflows. They have inputs and outputs to feed them data and get out results. The following types are available.

- JavaScript action
- Docker container action
- composite run steps action

Further in-depth description: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/about-actions